# Auto block of all JavaScript on many sites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settings

I feel this is something that is either not obvious to fix, or a significant bug in google chrome.

Basically when I had a javascript error that created a "death loop"(infinite loop) to save my memory chrome shut off JavaScript. This part seems like a good idea, however to test if it is fixed a developer must have the ability to turn it back on.

However after it happened I am unable to get JavaScript to work properly anywhere. If I do not try to open dev tools it will work, though I have noticed it get blocked occasionally. The main trigger is the opening of dev tools from what i can see, as soon as I open it JavaScript will turn off. This makes it next to impossible to watch console reports through chrome, I had to use firefox/another computer.

Has anyone else had this problem? is there and easy fix I am missing?

I have tried deleting cache, changing settings, reinstalling chrome, nothing has any effect.

EDIT: -1? obviously this does not seem to be a problem for other people, I will try to expand on this.

If I open up a web page. lets say google.com. Thin it right click and inspect element, no more JavaScript (and yes it even happens on google). My Javascript settings are to allow ALL sites to use JavaScript and there is no exceptions (this is the settings area that the "blocker" takes me to).

There are 2 option with the blocker, allow Javascript from "DOMAIN" and continue to block. allow will do nothing, and block will add it to the exceptions to block. If anyone wants to trigger this, here is a similar bit of code that I ran that caused it. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK:

```
var ii=0; //just to make sure the loop runs
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
for(var i=0;ii<arr.length;i++){
  console.log('running');
}
```

You can see it was just a simple typo, yet it seems something like this, at least for me has crippled chrome completely.

This question has gotten some bad reviews. So below is an updated version of the issue I had encountered.

**Without any kind of known user input, chrome stopped executing JavaScript regardless of its settings**

So this was the question as I meant it to be, although most likely due to frustration might of not spent enough time to properly word it:

**How do you turn on JavaScript when chrome seemingly turns it off by default? Outside of the JavaScript settings**

I then would expand to explain that it happens when used with dev tools, and being a web developer a rarely close it. However I did eventually figure it out as I explained in an answer below, its just the settings for dev tools is separated from chromes settings, making it easy to not notice that dev tools can turn off JavaScript on its own.

I hope this can help out people who encounter this situation, it was frustrating for me and I spent a good 2-3 hours looking for answers on it and found nothing, so considering I was googling about Google chrome, that seems far to long for something so simple that can be so easy to miss.

Comment: Set a breakpoint instead of logging to the console!

Comment: Did you check your Chrome preferences or dev tools settings to make sure that JS is not disabled?

Comment: JS is not disabled, not blocked on any site, yet it will block javascript anyway. I only use logging to test that statements are running properly, they are never left in the code. But using dev tools seems to be one of the key factors that tells chrome to shut off JavaScript. however without dev tools my job would take far longer as I would have to use old fashioned alerts to tell me that code is running. Even then JavaScript still shuts off occasionally (other computers dev tools show no spike in memory usage).

Comment: Looks like other people seem to be noticing this as well. https://twitter.com/StuRobson/status/338945675947544576. Does that seem to be the same problem you're having?

Comment: Yes I have located the problem, though i since it was just "not obvious to fix" I will get this answered. Matt Ball was on the right track. I did not take the part dev tools settings seriously. Chrome has 2 settings for Javascript and the dev tools settings can override chromes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the separation of settings between chrome and dev tools. The dev tools are able to override the settings of chrome and since dev tools is stand alone, it is hard to notice the settings icon. I have used dev tools for years never needing to change its settings. So in my opinion this is something perhaps for chrome to make a little more apparent, but now hopefully this answer can help people who have went through the same strain that I did.

When you click the bottom right corner of dev tools you are taken to settings. In here if for whatever reason chrome deemed that the JavaScript that was running is dangerous, it will shut off all JavaScript on any page you have dev tools open. Inside "general" of the dev tools settings there is a checkbox for "disable javascript". This will fix issues with dev tools and JavaScript.